# turn a jQuery AJAX call into a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery AJAX call that I will need to do multiple times so I want to turn it into a function but not sure how. Here's the code. Any ideas? I know it seems trivial but I've looked around and don't know how to properly do this...

```
//This does the ajax call to show the actual creative
    $('#creative').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/app/components/MailingsReport.cfc',
            //POST method is used
            type: "POST",
            //pass the data 
            data: {
                method: "getCreativeHTML",
                creativeID: $('#creative').val(),
                datasource: "shopping_cart"
                 },
            dataType: "html",
            //contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(response){
                var obj = $.trim(response);
                //alert("response");
                if (obj == '"0 records"') {
                    $('#preview').html("No creative found.");
                }
                else { 
                    $('#htmlCode').val( obj );
                    $('#preview').html( obj );
                }
            }
        })
        //if there was an error, when user clicks into field hightlight-error is removed
        $('#htmlCode').change(function(){
            $('#reloadContent').show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just wrap it... `function() { <code> }`

Comment: just wrap it in side function foo(){} , and call foo();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function foo(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/app/components/MailingsReport.cfc',
            //POST method is used
            type: "POST",
            //pass the data 
            data: {
                method: "getCreativeHTML",
                creativeID: $('#creative').val(),
                datasource: "shopping_cart"
                 },
            dataType: "html",
            //contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(response){
                var obj = $.trim(response);
                //alert("response");
                if (obj == '"0 records"') {
                    $('#preview').html("No creative found.");
                }
                else { 
                    $('#htmlCode').val( obj );
                    $('#preview').html( obj );
                }
            }
        });
}
```

And the call :

```
$('#creative').change(function(e) { return foo(e); });
```

Comment: Good point!! Specifing the EventObject e gives you more control on the bound function. ([JQuery .change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/))

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
     //parameres
    });
```

is actually a simple function call,

```
$.ajax(parameters);
```

you just can wrap it ina function like any similar function calls like:

```
add(1,2);
```

If you are using some variables in AJAX call parameter eg:myUrl, then make sure its available in the scope were you call the function.

A simple example:

```
function sendRquest(myUrl){ 
$.ajax({
    url : myUrl,
    //other parameters
    });
}
```